# When I send mail through Google Script it doesn't take CSS style

Tags: css, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I designed a signature to send with each email, I did this in the notepad when I open the page can see a decent signature. But when I send that code in the mail, it seems that it did not take the CSS.

I'm using Google Apps Script and the following code:

```
 function prueba_firma(){
    var AxId = "ID_Image";
  var logo = DriveApp.getFileById(AxId).getBlob();
  var asunto = "PRUEBAS FIRMA";
  var correo="Remitente";
  var copia="Correos en copia";

/*CSS style of signature*/
  var firmastyle = "p + p {text-indent: 0em;margin-top: -13px;}"+
    "p{LINE-HEIGHT:15px;}"+
".vl {border-right: 4px solid #03145B;height: 145px;right: 30%;margin-left: -2px;margin-right: -25px;}"+
"#contenedor{height: 250px;width: 564px;padding:1px;color:#000;overflow:hidden;margin-top: 30px;}"+
"#infosg{font-family:sans-serif;font-size:small;font-weight: bolder;float:right;padding:1px;color:#021B8C;"+
"width:250px;margin:5px;}"+
"#imgsg{float:left;padding:1px;color:#000;width:270px;margin-top:2px;}"+
".graos{color: #7d7d7d;}"+
".gracl{color: #808080;}"+
".nd{color:#021B8C;}"+
".mgd{font-weight: 900;font-size:15px;}";
  var descrpt="PRUEBA FIRMA";

/*Body of the signature*/
    var firma = "<div id='contenedor'><h3> Cordialmente. </h3>"+
"<div id='infosg'><p><p class='mgd'>Analista de Desarrollo.</p>"+
"<p class='graos mgd'>Servicio al cliente.<br/></p><p/>"+
"<p>w. <a href='www.page.com'>www.page.com</a></p>"+
"<p class='gracl'><a class='nd'>t.</a> +57 1 5897447 Ext. 1209.</p>"+
"<p>e.  <a href='mailto:email@gmail.com?Subject=Solicitud"+
"%20de%20soporte'>email@gmail.com</a> </p>"+
"<p class='gracl'>Carrera x # xx - xx Torre x Of. xxx.</p>"+
"<p>Bogotá, Colombia  </p>"+
"</div><div id='imgsg'><div class='vl'><img height='90' width='200' style='margin-left: 2px' src='cid:Axlogo'></div> </div></div> ";
 var descrpt="Breve descripción en el texto del correo";
/*body and style union*/
  var cuerpoAv = "<!DOCTYPE html>"+"<html>"+"<head> "+"<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>"+"<style>"+firmastyle+"</style>"+"</head>"+
 "<h4> Cordial saludo. </h4>"+"<div id='m_body'>"+descrpt+ "</div>"+firma+"</html>";

/*Send email, it works fine*/
GmailApp.sendEmail(correo,asunto,"",{cc: copia,htmlBody: cuerpoAv, inlineImages:{Axlogo: logo}});
}
```

What happens is that the `<p>` objects are not being removed line spacing. The results are the following:

**Signature developed in notepad viewed in my browser:**
[image]

**Signature in the mail sent:**
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that. I took it like a mail subject and so I sent in capital letters, your comment will consider for next time. Thank you. PD: I'm using Google translate, I hope that apology sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps someone, after many attempts, I managed to remove the space between paragraphs with the following:

```
p + p {text-indent: 0em;margin-top: -13px;LINE-HEIGHT:4px;}
```

I have no idea why the view in the browser is far from what is seen in gmail but it already works.